# Execute code with Application Pool load

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, iis, application-pool

My website was always a single **vb.net project** with tons of pages and classes inside (i don't like it).

Now i need to use some of those classess from **external C# applications**. So i made a new **vb.net dll** with all the legacy code and use it from both `ASP.NET` website and `C#` application.

Sadly, some of my classess reads configuration from `web.config` (two of them are `static`). If they are inside an external dll file they **cannot access** the `web.config` file, so i want to remove any reference to it and configure them when application pool loads, **before any page load**.

Is this possible? I'm doing my searches without any success!

Thank you!

Comment: can you clarify your solution structure and your web.config reading code? being in a linked dll shouldnt stop you reading web or app config

Comment: well, it turns out my question was pretty dumb, i can use `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings()` even from my dll importing `System.configuration` into my legacy dll! thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of the dependancy injection pattern

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public class NewConfigClass
        {
            public string MyConfigParameter {get;set;}
        }

        public class LegacyNeedsConfig
        {
            public string ConfigurableSetting {get;set;}
            public LegacyNeedsConfig(NewConfigClass config)
            {
                this.ConfigurableSetting = config.MyConfigParameter;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            NewConfigClass config = new NewConfigClass();
            config.MyConfigParameter = "hello world"; //read from web or app config

            LegacyNeedsConfig legacy = new LegacyNeedsConfig(config);

            Console.WriteLine(legacy.ConfigurableSetting);
        }

    }
}
```